# WPF Grid/WrapPanel AutoSize Animation

Tags: wpf, animation, grid, itemssource

I have the following layout in WPF

```
<grid>
<row height=auto>
<border>
<listbox>
<border?
</row>
<row height=*>
<othercontent>
</row>
</grid>
```

Using MVVM and have listbox itemsource bound.  I am using a wrapPanel in the grid, and have scrolling disabled so the Grid row height will grow and shrink based on the list box contents.  This is all working fine.

What I would like, is to be able to animate the growing and shrinking of the listbox (or the border containing it, or the grid row that has the auto-height).  What element should I be using - a trigger on SizeChanged on the border?

Also I when my ItemsSource changes, I would like my listbox items to fade out, then the resize, then the new items to fade in.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230793/method-called-in-wpf-when-window-size-changes

Comment: "Direct routed events do not follow a route, they are only handled within the same element on which they are raised. Direct routed events do support other routed event behavior: they support an accessible handlers collection, and can be used as an EventTrigger in a style." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to create you own WrapPanel. Perhaps there already is a 3rd party control out there that does what you want.

Not sure how this could be done. But a custom wrap panel. On size change check if there is room for item on row. If so execute storyboars that will animate the item's position.

Also take a look at visual state manager. If using fluid layout you will be able to animate stuff that doesn't animate. Like moving uielement out of a grid column to another.

Not sure if this is of any help.

Comment: Just found this link. Maybe that could help. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/23/537966.aspx