# Method called in WPF when window size changes?

Tags: wpf

I am creating a application using WPF. I want to calculate the coordinate of the visible region of a canvas.

Which method will be called when i resize the window, so that i can calculate the coordinate when the window is resized?

Comment: Please revise all your questions and mark answers as correct if thery are correct.

Answer (score 9):

The [`SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) event will be raised, you can add an event handler there. But maybe your particular problem has another solution (there's too little information in your question).

Answer (score 3):

Provide SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" just like below:

```
<Window x:Class="SalesPlus.DataViews"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Contacts"
    Height="600"
    Width="1200"
    SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
```

Then in your Window_SizeChanged method you can have the updated sizes as follows:

```
        private void Window_SizeChanged (object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        var ah = ActualHeight;
        var aw = ActualWidth;
        var h = Height;
        var w = Width;
        Console.WriteLine ("ActualHeight(updated height value): {0}, ActualWidth(updated width value): {1}, Height(before size change): {2}, Width(before size change): {3}", ah, aw, h, w);
        }
//output:
// ActualHeight(updated height): 744, ActualWidth(updated width): 1382, Height(before size change): 600, Width(before size change): 1200
```